# Making a sign one column vertically. Don't know anything about Japanese

Tags: grammar, spelling

I'm helping a friend making a vertical neon sign for an installation with the word hikikomori. As I don't know anything about Japanese I just googled the translation, but can't understand how to order the characters. Should I just take 引き籠もり and then place one character on each line as read from top to bottom like:

引

き

籠

も

り

Or should the order be the other way around when writing vertically? Languages are just not my thing...

Comment: that's fine, top down.

Comment: I would really love to see how the character 籠 is created using glass tubes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should like this:

[image]

- You can just place each character from top to bottom, without
  rotating. For details, please see [Horizontal and vertical writing in
  East Asian scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_and_vertical_writing_in_East_Asian_scripts)
- The word *hikikomori* is usually written as ひきこもり, in all-[hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana#Table_of_hiragana). Avoid complicated kanji 引 and 籠. The latter is probably impossible to reproduce with a neon tube, anyway.